# Java call object in an other class constructor

Tags: java

I'm developing a personal app for password manager and I'm stuck when passing an object in an other class constructor. My problem is how to use it. Here is the code:

```
public class Account {
    public String username, email;
    public Password password;

    public Account(String username, String email, Password password){
        this.username = username;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

And here the code of Password class:

```
public class Password {
    public String password;
    public char[] passwordArray;

    public Password(String password){
        this.password = password;
    }

    public Password(int length){
        passwordArray = new char[length];
    }
}
```

In the main how can I give a Password class to the Account object?

```
public static void main() {
    Account a1 = new Account("test", "test@test", ?);
}
```

Comment: You don't "call" objects. Where exactly is it in the code that you're trying to do something, what what are you trying to do? *Create* an object? Store a reference to an object? Call a method on the object?

Comment: Is there an error message you're getting?

Comment: your constructors looks fine, where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect that you might be getting some compile time errors.

In the Account class there seem to be two syntax errors.

1: The main method signature needs a formal parameter of type String array.

2: The Account constructor expects a third actual argument of type Password.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Account a1 = new Account("test", "test@test", new Password("Hello"));
}
```

As for the Password class I don't see that there is a method declaration for "rand" that indexes into the char Arrays. Maybe you could declare an instance variable of Type java.util.Random, and slightly adjust the method calls to use Random.nextInt(int). This will return a random integer that is from 0 (inclusive) to the specified value (exclusive).

```
 private Random rand = new java.util.Random();

 public void generateRandom(char how){
    switch(how){
        case 'a':
            for(int i = 0; i < passwordArray.length; i++){
                passwordArray[i] = alphabet[rand.nextInt(alphabet.length)];
            }
            .
            .
            .
```